# I'm trying to decrement using a while loop without incorporating a flag value within the while loop body

Tags: python

I'm trying to decrement using a while loop without using a flag value within the body of the while loop. I was wondering why I was getting an infinite loop from this code. I'm not sure if the reason is because integers are immutable and it constantly gets overwritten in condition.

```
end_number = 500 
i = 0


while i < end_number:
    print("I'm decrementing in percentages of 10")
    end_number = end_number - (end_number * 0.10)
```

Comment: make it `end_number -= 50` to make it decrement by a fixed amount, 10% of the original number.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment is asymptotic to zero.

```
end_number = end_number - (end_number * 0.10)
```

will approach zero, but never get there. No matter how small `end_number` gets, 90% of it will still be greater than zero. So, your loop never exits.

That's the abstract, mathematically correct answer. Your issue is *slightly* different in the details, due to the limitations of floating point math. There comes a point when 10% of end_number is rounded down to zero, so you have `end_number = tiny float - 0`, and end_number stays at that value forever more.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the loop and pint end_number you will see that it is 0. so your loop never exits.. the problem is 10% smaller of itself every time will never reach 0.

you need to change your assignment. what you need to do is this

```
end_number = 500 
incrementer = end_number * 0.10
i = 0

while i < end_number:
    print("I'm decrementing in percentages of 10")
    end_number = end_number - incrementer
```